# Code else eclipse----> delete token

Tags: java, android, if-statement, webview

```
Because the eclipse was error:
```

else delete token????
the code is this:

```
public void go(View v)
    {
     String a= url.getText().toString();
    if (a.contains("www.") == true); {
     webView.loadUrl(url.getText().toString());
     }
    else {
     String search = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+url.getText(); 
     webView.loadUrl(search);
     }
     }
```

PLease help me

Comment: Is the full error: "Syntax error on token 'else', delete this token"?

Comment: Off topic but you could do `if (a.contains("www.")) {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `if` statement requires a body - remove the semi-colon

```
if (a.contains("www.") == true); {
                               ^
```

Comment: programmig is in the small things :D

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a.contains("www.") == true);
```

==

```
if (a.contains("www.") == true) { }
```

Which does nothing. So `webView.loadUrl(url.getText().toString());` will be always executed since it's in an *inner block*.

If you're using an IDE, you can make it warn you of things like that (empty `if` statements).

---

You're getting an error because your code is:

```
if (a.contains("www.") == true) { } 
{
  //some code
}
else {

}
```

But the `else` has *no* `if` before it..

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
if (a.contains("www.") == true); {
```

with this

```
if (a.contains("www.") == true) {
```